# network issue in cyanogenmod 13 in Redmi 1s

Tags: cyanogenmod, mobile-network, xiaomi

I have installed cyanogen-mod 13 as custom Rom in my android phone. Now, I found a problem in network connectivity. While connecting data(3G), after sometimes, 3G data automatically shifting to 2G data. I have set APN settings based on service provider(automatically set).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Open dialer, and type `*#*#4636#*#*`.

It will enter into `Testing mode`.

Inside that, tap on Phone Information, look for `Set preferred network type`, and set it as `WCDMA only`.

This `Setting` will be lost after a reboot.